# Using read without losing the TAB

Tags: bash

Im using read in a while loop to automatically change a makefile after download.

Here is part of the script,

```
    while read a; do
    if [[ "$a" = "FCOMPL=g77" ]]
    then echo "FCOMPL=gfortran" >> makefile
    elif [[ "$a" = "FFLAGC=-Wall -O" ]]
    then echo "FFLAGC=-Wall -O -fno-backslash" >> makefile
    else
    echo $a >> makefile
    fi
    done <makefile.orig
```

The problem is that I lose the tabulation.

Any idea of how I can avoid that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using bash to do the task, you could learn `sed`:

```
sed -e 's/^FCOMPL=g77$/FCOMPL=gfortran/' \
    -e '/^FFLAGC=-Wall -O$/s/$/ -fno-backslash/' makefile.orig > makefile
```

Each `-e` gives `sed` a command to perform.  In this case (1st -e), the `s` command performs a **substitution**: `s/foo/bar/` replaces the 1st occurrence of `foo` on each line by `bar`.  To be sure we work on complete line, I added `^` (beginning of the line) and `$` (end of the line).

You can prefix a command by a selector.  In this case (2nd -e), the `s` command is applied only to a line matching `^FFLAGC=-Wall -O$`.

You could even use the `-i` flag to replace the file:

```
sed -i -e 's/^FCOMPL=g77$/FCOMPL=gfortran/' \
       -e '/^FFLAGC=-Wall -O$/s/$/ -fno-backslash/' makefile
```

Answer (score 5):

Found a solution!!
I applied what is taught here http://en.kioskea.net/faq/1757-how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line

```
    old_IFS=$IFS      # save the field separator           
    IFS=$'\n'     # new field separator, the end of line
    (code)
    IFS=$old_IFS     # restore default field separator
```